# Checking if parent element is button while divs in for loop

Tags: javascript, html

I need to check; if a button is exists before content div.

How can I do this with pure `javascript`? I did try `parentElement.tagName` and `parentNode.tagName` but did't worked.

ADDITIONAL DESCRIPTION: I am trying listing div contens and I will put button with createElement if button is not there before content div. (Please note: createElement is not part of this quesiton, I know already how can I do)

My example is here:

```js
const test = document.querySelectorAll('[id="test"] > .content');

for (let x = 0; x < test.length; x++) {
  console.log(test[x].parentElement.tagName);
  console.log(test[x].parentNode.tagName);
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div class="content">1</div>
  <div class="content">2</div>
  <button class="button">TEST 3</button>
  <div class="content">3</div>
  <div class="content">4</div>
  <div class="content">5</div>
</div>
```

JSFIDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/juq2c4se/1/

Comment: it should be `tagName` not `TagName`. Javacript is CaSe sEnSiTivE

Comment: Sorry your are right, I did write TagName instead tagName. I did fixed now on jsfidle. But result is always : div (There is a button tag before content 3)

Comment: @Majed Badawi thank you for jsfiddle run code snippet. I don't know how can I do this.

Comment: parent?  you can't put a div in a button tag.  do you mean previous sibling?

Comment: Maybe I was wrong with parent.element.I am trying make test with previous sibling now. I just trying listing div contens and I will put button with createElement if button is not there before content div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`previousElementSibling.tagName` should help:

```js
const test = document.querySelectorAll('[id="test"] > .content');
for (let x = 0; x < test.length; x++) {
  const contentElem = test[x];
  if(!contentElem.previousElementSibling || contentElem.previousElementSibling.tagName!=='BUTTON') {
    const btn = document.createElement("btn");
    btn.innerHTML = `<button class="button">TEST ${x+1}</button>`;
    contentElem.parentNode.insertBefore(btn, contentElem);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div class="content">1</div>
  <div class="content">2</div>
  <button class="button">TEST 3</button>
  <div class="content">3</div>
  <div class="content">4</div>
  <div class="content">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. is it possible with content 1 div too? (I am listing div contens and I will put button with create element if button is not there before content div)

Comment: @webmaster you're welcome. Technically, content 1 div doesn't have a previous sibling element since it's the first but I think you can consider this edge case when creating the condition for example: ``!test[x].previousElementSibling || test[x].previousElementSibling.tagName!=='BUTTON'``

Comment: I did try this but result is always +1 more. If one button is there result is 2 but if button is not there result is 1 instead of 0. https://jsfiddle.net/aq38zts1/

Comment: @webmaster I think I got what you're trying to do, answer updated.

Comment: Yes I was looking for a answer like this. Sorry for my English, maybe I could not explain exactly totally.I just wanted; put a button if button is not there before content div. Thank you for answer and thanks for the all answers.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between parent and sibling.
In your case  div id="test" is the parent.
Since you are looking for a "button before content div" then you need a sibling, and if I understand you correctly then you need to use test[i].previousElementSibling.tagName
Read more about Node.previousElementSibling here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling

Answer (score 0):

Make use of **tagName** NOT **TagName**.
change this: `console.log(test[x].parentElement.TagName)`
to `console.log(test[x].parentElement.tagName)`;

The **t** on the tagName should be small case.
You can read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName .

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I did already fixed my fault (TagName -> tagName) on jsfiddle. And also I edited question with tagName. Problem is not related with tagName now.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm having a hard time understanding your question as [`<button>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) can not have nested elements.  So here's how you would figure out where the button is related to it's [siblings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) and [parent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement) based on tag names.

```
const container = document.getElementById('test');
const firstButton = container.getElementsByTagName('button')[0]
if(firstButton) {
  const divBefore = firstButton.previousElementSibling.nodeName === 'DIV'
  const divAfter = firstButton.nextElementSibling.nodeName === 'DIV'
  const divParent = firstButton.parentElement.nodeName === 'DIV'
}
```

I'm using a `getElementById` to limit the scope for `getElementsByTagName`